# kernel32.dll symbolic link

Tags: python

ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("kernel32.dll") is not creating symbolic links when not in admin mode. is it possible to copy this dll into D: and read from there. What are the repurcussions if any.

```
import ctypes
inpt = "D:/mayaslate/symlink/ssh0155_plate.0003.jpg"
output = "D:/imagesequence/ssh0155_plate/ssh0155_plate.1003.jpg"
kdll = ctypes.windll.LoadLibrary("D:/mayaslate/kernel32.dll") <--- is this possible
kdll.CreateSymbolicLinkA(inpt , output, 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still won't have any admin permissions, even if you load the `dll` file from another location.

Comment: could you explain/confirm that specific in the above context. you mean even if i copy dll to D: ( where user has full permission ), you are saying above code will not give any result

Comment: As far as I know the location of the executable file doesn't affect the permission during execution.